# Opencart - trying to create a blog

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to create a blog on my opencart website with a pretty much standard layout where a left column has a list of blog posts with the latest at the top and a right divided into 2 - archive (list of months which drop down to reveal posts in that month), and top stories which shows 5 posts with the most amount of comments.

I appreciate there are extensions out there, but the best looking ones are all commercial and i want to replicate this so i (and others) can customize it the way we want.

Comment: @capellic Well not exactly, i'd like to learn how to do something like this myself. i've found a vqmod that integrates what i want in the left column with the admin backend allowing me to make posts in there. Just need to figure out how to make the right column call posts as mentioned above

Comment: you're right, it's interesting. Maybe you could give some detail about in question body. That vqmod could be interesting to me also. I'll go to search...

Comment: sorry what detail did you want? for the vqmod click here http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=7684&filter_search=news&filter_license=0&page=1